# Postgres, implement optimistic lock

Tags: postgresql, scala, concurrency

I have multiple service instances, they compete for job execution. My goals

- a job must be assigned to one of service instances.
- service can't run more than 2 jobs at a time
  Here is my SQL query:

```sql
select 
  id -- some fields omitted for brevity
from JOBS
where (
  jobStatus = 'ACCEPTED' -- job waits for execution, 
  and executorId is null -- none of service instances got a job
  and (
    select count(*)
    from JOBS
    where (
      jobStatus in (
        'ACCEPTED',  -- service took the job for execution
        'PROCESSING' -- service executes job
      )
      and executorId = 'service_instance_id'
    )
  ) <= 2 -- each service instance should run not more than 2 jobs at a time
)
order by createdAt desc
limit 1
for update skip locked -- to avoid locks
```

then scala code

```scala
val selectForUpdateQuery = generateQuery() // example above
val ps = conn.prepareStatement(selectForUpdateQuery, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)
val rs = ps.executeQuery()
        if (rs.next()) {
          val now = OffsetDateTimeFactory.nowOffsetDateTime()
          val jobRecord = resultSetRowToJobRecord(rs).copy(executorId = Some(executorId), updatedAt = now)
          val sqlTimestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(now.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime())

          rs.updateString("executorId", executorId)
          rs.updateObject("updatedAt", sqlTimestamp)
          rs.updateRow()
          logger.info(s"job ${rs.getLong("id")} was acquired by executorId: $executorId at: $now")
          Some(jobRecord)
        } else {
          None
        }
```

test:

```scala
      val jobsWithExecutor = withClue(s"executor should acquire not more than 2 jobs") {
        Future
          .sequence(
            (1 to 100)
              .map { _ =>
                jobService.acquireExecutorLockAtJob(executorId, concurrencyLimit = 2).map {
                  case None => None
                  case aJob @ Some(job) =>
                    logger.info(s"job: $job acquired by executorId: $executorId")
                    aJob
                }
              }
          )
          .futureValue
          .flatten
      }
```

executor gets up to 10 jobs. Don't understand what do I do wrong.

What do I expected, let's focus on single executor named `service_instance_id`

- job inserted into DB with jobStatus=`ACCEPTED` and executorId=null
- executor polls DB, submits query above `service_instance_id`
- query skips locked rows do avoid any sort of locking, other executors could try to lock same record
- query locks first available record (order by createdAt desc limit 1)
- jdbc client sets `rs.updateString("executorId", executorId)`
- commit happens
- query will return no records if executor already has 2 assigned jobs.

Comment: `executorId = 'service_instance_id'` ?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: It just looks like there is an error in that query, that would actually explain the behavior you are describing: the condition `executorId = 'service_instance_id' ` is always false, so your subquery will return 0.

Comment: that subquery counts how many `ACCEPTED `, `PROCESSING `,  `service_instance_id` have at the moment. Each service instance has it's own unique`service_instance_id`

Comment: Yes, but in your query `service_instance_id` is a string literal ...

Comment: ah, it's passed as parameter. I did set concrete value. service instance sets it's host name which is unique

Comment: Well, I don't see your code setting it anywhere. Perhaps you should read up on how to [create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: But in general, I don't quite understand how you expect this to do what you want at all: if 10  queries with the same executor id run in parallel before any job is assigned, each of them will get `0` as the subquery result. So, what specifically do you expect to happen that would prevent 10 jobs from being assigned to the same executor?

Comment: It's ok to have 2 jobs per executor, it's not ok to run more than 2 jobs on the same executor. I'll update post with expected execution flow, obviously I did smth wrong..

Comment: Consider a case, when you have 10 jobs sitting in postgres, and none is assigned to an executor yet. If you run 10 queries in parallel with the same executor id, then the subquery will give 0 to each of them (because nothing is assigned yet). So each one will grab a job, and you get 10 jobs assigned to the same executor. This is what is happening in your test.